# option resetting after typing a value

Tags: reactjs

Basically, when the user chooses the "other" option an input appears and he will be able to type his own text and store it inside a variable in the global context.

The problem is when the user types a value it changes to the first option in my list of options.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAppContext } from "../context/appContext";

const FormRowSelect = ({
  labelText,
  name,
  value,
  handleChange,
  list,
  optionsIsActivated,
}) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(""); // new state variable
  var newList = [...list, "other"];

  const { handleChange2 } = useAppContext(); // because i already used handleChange i made another function 

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
    console.log(inputValue);
    console.log(inputValue);
    console.log(e.target.value);
    handleChange2({ name, value: inputValue });
  };
  return (
    <div className="formRow">
      <label htmlFor={name} className="form-label">
        {labelText || name}
      </label>

      <select
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        className="form-select choosebtn"
        style={{ color: "black" }}
      >
        {newList.map((itemValue, index) => {
          return (
            <option key={index} value={itemValue}>
              {itemValue}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>

      {optionsIsActivated && !list.includes(value) && (
        <>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={inputValue}
            name={name}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            className="form-input other-input"
          />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormRowSelect;
```

**handleChange function**

```
const handleChange2 = ({ name, value }) => {
    dispatch({ type: "HANDLE_CHANGE", payload: { name, value } });
  };
```

**Here is how I used my component (in case you need it):**

```
import { useAppContext } from "../../context/appContext";
import Wrapper from "../../assets/wrappers/DashboardFormPage";
import {
  FormRow,
  Alert,
  FormRowSelect,
  CheckBoxOptions,
} from "../../components";
import CheckBox from "../../components/checkBox";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const AllCustomer = () => {
  const {
    isLoading,
    isEditing,
    showAlert,
    handleChange,
    clearValues,
   
    companypercentage,
    companypercentageOptions,
  
  } = useAppContext();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  const handleJobInput = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    // console.log(`${name} : ${value}`);

    handleChange({ name, value });
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <form className="form">
        <h3>{isEditing ? "edit job" : "add job"}</h3>
        {showAlert && <Alert />}
        <div className="form-center">
          
          <FormRowSelect
            name="companypercentage"
            value={companypercentage}
            handleChange={handleJobInput}
            list={companypercentageOptions}
            optionsIsActivated={true}
            labelText="companyPercentage:"
          />
          
          
          <div className="btn-container">
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="btn btn-block submit-btn"
              onClick={handleSubmit}
              disabled={isLoading}
            >
              submit
            </button>
            <button
              className="btn btn-block submit-btn"
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                clearValues();
              }}
            >
              clear
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default AllCustomer;
```

Here is my appContext.js

```
const initialState = {
 
  companypercentage: "قيد الانتظار", // I'm trying this 
  companypercentageOptions: ["قيد الانتظار"],

  excesscashcustomer: "قيد الانتظار",
  excesscashcustomerOptions: ["قيد الانتظار"],
  
};

const handleChange = ({ name, value }) => {
    dispatch({ type: "HANDLE_CHANGE", payload: { name, value } });
  };
  const handleChange2 = ({ name, value }) => { //i duplicated as a temporarily solution for myhandleChange event
    dispatch({ type: "HANDLE_CHANGE", payload: { name, value } });
  };
 return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...state,
        
        handleChange1,
        handleChange2,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useAppContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext);
};

export { AppProvider, initialState, useAppContext };
```

reducer.js

```
if (action.type === HANDLE_CHANGE) {
    return {
      ...state,
      [action.payload.name]: action.payload.value,
      page: 1,
    };
  }
```

when start typing in the "other" input value options are resetting to the first index. I want it to stay on "other"

Comment: Can you provide the data storage setup? how are you writing your store with that dispatch and why are you adding the `other` option after the fact? can you store that in your global store? I suspect this issue is from your component re-rendering from the global store update. It could be your elements are unmounted and remounted. I would change your key to be the option value specifically, vs using its index in an array.

Comment: I edited the question with the updated code. Also why djd I store it in the same component ? basically because I'm trying to reduce fields in global context becuase i'm gonna use the component 7 more times for better performance maybe.

Comment: basically the idea is when my value is "other", the user could type his own answer in the input field.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you only remove the "value" option from the  tag, your issue will be solved.
The value shown in the select will be handled by your options.

You can have a "defaultValue" in your  if you wish, but also not needed.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Even after removing the value from the input tag , it still resetting , also i updated the code including my global context